# react-bootstrap: clear element value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap

I'm  trying to clear my input fields after an `onClick` event.

I'm using `react-bootstrap` library and while there is a `getValue()` method, there is not `setValue(value)` method.

I've stumbled upon this [discussion](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/360) .

I did not fully understand what they are suggesting in order to simply clean a form after submission.

After all, If I would use a simple HTML `<input>` instead of `react-bootstrap` I could grab the node via element `ref` and set it's value to be empty string or something.

What is considered a react way to clean my react-bootstrap `<Input />` element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the state in your React component, set the element value via props, get the element value via event callbacks.  Here is an example:

Here is an example taken directly from their documentation.  I just added a `clearInput()` method to show you you can clear the input by just updating the state of your component.  This will trigger a re-render which will cause the input value to update.

```
const ExampleInput = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      value: ''
    };
  },

  validationState() {
    let length = this.state.value.length;
    if (length > 10) return 'success';
    else if (length > 5) return 'warning';
    else if (length > 0) return 'error';
  },

  handleChange() {
    // This could also be done using ReactLink:
    // http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html
    this.setState({
      value: this.refs.input.getValue()
    });
  },

  // Example of how you can clear the input by just updating your state
  clearInput() {
    this.setState({ value: "" });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <Input
        type="text"
        value={this.state.value}
        placeholder="Enter text"
        label="Working example with validation"
        help="Validation is based on string length."
        bsStyle={this.validationState()}
        hasFeedback
        ref="input"
        groupClassName="group-class"
        labelClassName="label-class"
        onChange={this.handleChange} />
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For what I'm doing at the moment, I didn't really think it was necessary to control the Input component's value through setState/Flux (aka I didn't want to deal with all the boilerplate)...so here's a gist of what I did. Hopefully the React gods forgive me.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Input } from 'react-bootstrap';

export class BootstrapForm extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.clearForm = this.clearForm.bind(this);
    this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this);
  }

  clearForm() {
    const fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email'];
    fields.map(field => {
      this.refs[field].refs['input'].value = '';
    });
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    // Handle submitting the form
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <div>
            <Input
              ref='firstName'
              type='text'
              label='First Name'
              placeholder='Enter First Name'
            />
            <Input
              ref='lastName'
              type='text'
              label='Last Name'
              placeholder='Enter Last Name'
            />
            <Input
              ref='email'
              type='email'
              label='E-Mail'
              placeholder='Enter Email Address'
            /> 
            <div>
              <Button bsStyle={'success'} onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
              <Button onClick={this.clearForm}>Clear Form</Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use FormControl as an input, and you want to use ref to change/get value from it, you use inputRef instead of ref

```
<FormControl inputRef={input => this.inputText = input} .../>
```

and use this to get/change its value:

```
this.inputText.value
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in case someone else is looking for an answer :D

You can access the values of react-bootstrap by using

```
console.log(e.target.form.elements.fooBar.value)
```

You can clear them by using

```
e.target.form.elements.fooBar.value = ""
```

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {Button, Form} from 'react-bootstrap';

    export default function Example(props) {

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    // Handle submitting the form
    }

    const resetSearch = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.target.form.elements.fooBar.value = ""
    }

    render() {
      return (
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} onReset={resetSearch} >
             <Form.Control type="input" name="fooBar" />  
             <Button type="submit">  Submit  </Button> 
             <Button onClick={resetSearch} type="submit" > Reset  </Button> 
          </Form>
          );
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, the easiest solution:)

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use ReactDOM:

```
<FormControl
  componentClass="select"
  ref="sStrike">
  <option value="-">Select&hellip;</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</FormControl>
```

Now a different FormControl fires an `onChange={handleChange}` and in that handler you can just id the `ref` and set to the default value:

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.sStrike).value = '-';
```

and that will set the select box to the 'default' value.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a button in-side form with the attribute type="reset"

```
<Button variant="primary" type="reset">Reset</Button>
```